# Why is newtype commonly used instead of type with the state monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad, newtype

Almost all of examples I've seen of the `State` Monad have been wrapped inside a `newtype`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative

data Bazzar 
  = Bazzar {
    valueOne :: Int      
  , valueTwo :: Int      
  }

newtype BazState a = BazState { unBazify :: State Bazzar a } 
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState Bazzar)
```

Are there any reasones why I shouldn't just make a type alias?

```
type BazState a = State Bazzar a
```

I realize the purpose of `newtype` is to differentiate between two different uses for the same type of data structure, like reimplementing type classes for existing types, or if you want to differentiate your use of the type from normal behavior. Or implement additional typeclasses for use of that class

If you're not doing any of the stuff mentioned above, isn't using `newtype` in this case just needless indirection?

Comment: You cannot define an instance for a type synonym.

Comment: Are you sure? I can enter `type Blah a = [(Int, a)]` into ghci with no problems. Oh wait, I just reread what you said, that fair enough.

Comment: The thing is though most of the examples I've seen don't implement any additional type classes. I'll update my question

Comment: It also lets you your api in such a way that you can export a monad or some other type for your library without exporting it's constructors, and if you need to change the underlying type in the future it's easier to do so without breaking the outward facing api.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't actually think about that as a use case, feel free to respond to the question with an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than being able to define instances for a newtype, you can use it as a "closed constructor" API for your library.  That way you export a single type without any constructors, along with functions that act as primitives and combinators so that users of your library can't construct invalid values of your type.  It also means that if you're careful enough, you can change the underlying structure without breaking the outward facing API.  A great example of this comes from Neil Mitchell, [who said in a recent post about modifying the Shake build system to use the `Continuation` monad](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2014/08/continuations-and-exceptions.html):

> The cool thing about Haskell is that I've been able to completely replace the underlying Shake `Action` monad from `StateT/IO`, to `ReaderT/IO`, to `ReaderT/ContT/IO`, without ever breaking any users of Shake.  Haskell allows me to produce effective and flexible abstractions.